# How do i add an App_Data folder in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, appdata

This is a silly question but How do I add an App_Data folder to a project? i have an xsd file that i want to include into the project.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

App_Data only exists for ASP.NET web sites and web applications.

If you have a web app or web site, right-click on the main node for the web site/app and pick "Add ASP.NET Folder" - this opens up a context submenu, which should contain "App_Data" as one of its options.

[image]

Marc

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project, add new folder and title it "AppData"

Comment: I followed your instructions but the new folder doesn't have that special folder icon that App_Data's usually have.

Comment: Maybe title it App_Data then?

Comment: Not all folders in visual studio gets special icons fyi.

Comment: I know App_Data and App_Code should have that special icon.

Comment: Ive seen a similar thing happen before where a project folder like App_Data didn't give the icon you normally see.  However, it doesn't effect anything besides the way it looks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue. If you have two options in your **"new project"** then select the one with the name: **"ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framwork)"** instead of the one with the name: **"ASP.NET Core Web Application"**

This is my troubleshoot and It worked for me :)